# Getting the nearest multiple of x of an integer thats equal or greater than the original value

Tags: c++

Lets say I have x = 25 and y = 4. I want the nearest value to x that is a) multiple of y and b) equal or greater than x, for these numbers it would be 28. Usually I would do this:

```
result = ceil((float)x / (float)y) * y
```

however, this time I'm dealing with uint64's and rather large numbers that would probably get chewed up by the conversion to a double and back so currently I'm doing this:

```
if (x % y) result = (x / y + 1) * y
else result = x
```

but I'm wondering if theres a better way since this has to come up a lot when dealing with files (i know it does for me)

Comment: The second piece of code looks pretty clear, why do you need a better way? If it's performance, are you sure this is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
z = x%y;
result = x + (z? y-z: 0);
```

No multiplication or division, and no danger of overflow (if the correct result can fit in the type).

Comment: Can you explain why is there a danger of overflow in the OP's case and why there's no such a danger in your code? What kind of overflow?

Comment: @user3564091: Suppose x=93, y=11 and the largest number the type can hold is 100. The correct answer is 99, but if the code involves a step like `x+y`, the addition will exceed the limit of the type, and the result will be something weird like 4 or -37 or even undefined behavior. Neither the OP's code nor mine has such a danger.